# Python - eval and show size of data read from stdin

Tags: python, size, stdin

I have a Python script that read lines from stdin such as:

```
# Read nmon data from stdin
data = sys.stdin.readlines()

# Number of lines read
nbr_lines = len(data)

# Show current time and number of lines
msg = now + " Reading NMON data: " + str(nbr_lines) + " lines"
print (msg)
```

I would have liked to eval and show the total amount of data in Bytes that has been read from stdin, is that possible ?

Thanks you for your help !

Comment: Are you reading python objects? why do you want to eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total amount of Bytes depends on encoding of your input.
For 8b encoding (e.g. ASCII) or if you just need to know the number of characters:

```
bytes_total = len(''.join(data))
```

Comment: Hi and thank you !
It works perfectly too ! (yes it will always be ASCII)

Comment: @Guilmxm: It seems very wasteful to join the strings back together after you just split them using readlines().  You don't need to join the whole text back together just to count its characters.

Comment: @John: Thanks for your comment, this is just the part of the code which reads data from stdin, i'm doing a large number of operations after this, so i guess the () after readlines shall be required no ?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = ['a','bcd','efgh']
>>> sum(map(len, data))
8
```